# React Native with Expo - Getting an exception “CameraManager.record is not a function” when trying to record with camera

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

Trying to get camera recording work and keep getting an exception.

I followed their basic example, but when I call recordAsync() it errors out.

Here’s my code

```
if (this.camera) {
this.camera.recordAsync().then(data => {
console.log(data);
Vibration.vibrate();
});
}
```

Here’s the exception that I get:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: CameraManager.record is not a function
TypeError: CameraManager.record is not a function
at Camera.recordAsync$
```

Any ideas? Seems like it's an issue with their code

Comment: Does the sdkVersion field in your app.json file match the "expo" package's version in package.json? And are you looking at docs for the same SDK version as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to know without more context, but I try some suggestions:

One important point is that Video recording requires both `Permissions.CAMERA` and `Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING`, are you asking for them?

Also, to use camera methods you need to update its reference using:

`<Camera ref={ref => { this.camera = ref; }} />`

Can you provide the reference you are following?